# Change Ownership Of Linux Directory

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions, readynas

I Have a Netgear ReadyNAS and have set up SFTP on it.
I created a user named "newuser" and changed directory to "newdirectory".

If I run the command `chown newuser * -R` inside of "newdirectory", will this change file ownership only on this directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running any command in bash, using the asterisk `*`, causes the shell to select all files and directories *in* the folder you are in right now. The `-R` flag will make sure the subdirectories and subfiles are modified aswell. Be aware, that the directory where you are itself will not be modified. If you want to modifiy the *current* folder, you should use the dot `.`.

**Summary:**

```
$ cd newdirectory/
$ chown newuser * -R
├─ newdirectory/     # not modified
│  ├─ subdirectory/  # modified
│  │   └── subfile/  # modified
│  └─ file           # modified

$ cd newdirectory/
$ chown newuser . -R
├─ newdirectory/     # modified
│  ├─ subdirectory/  # modified
│  │   └── subfile/  # modified
│  └─ file           # modified
```